# Iterating over rules using if else

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement

I have a main table with the rates of each product and their respective categories for package and risk.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'package': {0: 'basic', 1: 'medium', 2: 'premium', 3:'basic', 4:'medium', 5:'premium'},
   'risk_bin': {0: 'good/mid', 1: 'good/mid', 2: 'good/mid', 3:'bad', 4:'bad',5:'bad'},
   'A': {0:0.012,1:0.022,2:0.032,3:0.05,4:0.06,5:0.07},
   'B': {0:0.013,1:0.023,2:0.033,3:0.051,4:0.061,5:0.071},
   'C': {0:0.014,1:0.024,2:0.034,3:0.052,4:0.062,5:0.072},
   'D': {0:0.015,1:0.025,2:0.035,3:0.053,4:0.063,5:0.073}})
df = df[df.columns[[4,5,0,1,2,3]]]
```

On the second table, I get the user options, and the user will be able to create as many rules as he wants for these products based on the other product rates. And these rules can apply for only a certain package or risk bin.

So, for the example below, the product B will have the rate of product A plus 5% only for basic package and good/mid risk. The product C will have the rates of D plus 10% for all packages and only for bad risk.

```
rules = pd.DataFrame({'rule': {0: '1', 1: '2'},
   'product1': {0: 'B', 1: 'C'},
   'relantioship': {0:'=',1:'='},
   'product2': {0:'A',1:'D'},
   'symbol': {0:'+',1:'-'},
   'value': {0:0.05,1:0.10},
   'package':{0:'basic',1:'all'},
   'risk': {0:'good/mid', 1:'bad'}})
 rules = rules[rules.columns[[5,1,3,2,6,7,0,4]]]
```

Because I can have as many rules as the user wants I need to create a loop, and then pass the values accordingly to the relationships defined.

```
df2 = df.reset_index()

rules_nc = rules['rule'].get_values()
nc_cnt = rules_nc.size     

for i in range(nc_cnt):
    if pd.isnull(rules['rule'][i]):
        break
    product_1 = rules['product1'][i]
    product_2 = rules['product2'][i]
    sym = str(rules['symbol'][i])
    val = rules['value'][i]
    pack= rules['package'][i]
    risk = rules['risk'][i]        

if (df2['risk_bin']==risk) & (df2['package']==pack):
        if sym=='+':
            df2[product_1] = df2[product_2] + val
        if sym=='-':
            df2[product_1] = df2[product_2] - val    
else:
     df2[product_1] =  df2[product_1]
```

When I do this, I get the error below:

```
 The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

This is the output that I'm expecting for this set of rules.

```
    results = pd.DataFrame({'package': {0: 'basic', 1: 'medium', 2: 'premium', 3:'basic', 4:'medium', 5:'premium'},
   'risk_bin': {0: 'good/mid', 1: 'good/mid', 2: 'good/mid', 3:'bad', 4:'bad',5:'bad'},
   'A': {0:0.012,1:0.022,2:0.032,3:0.05,4:0.06,5:0.07},
   'B': {0:0.062,1:0.023,2:0.033,3:0.1,4:0.061,5:0.071},
   'C': {0:0.014,1:0.024,2:0.034,3:0.153,4:0.163,5:0.173},
   'D': {0:0.015,1:0.025,2:0.035,3:0.053,4:0.063,5:0.073}})

results = results[results.columns[[4,5,0,1,2,3]]]
```

Can you please help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide the output you'd expect given the input you provided? This is likely a job for `pandas.merge()` rather than a iteration: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: @smj the rules and number of rules can change accordingly to the user, how I suppose to use pandas.merge() to solve this? Can you give an example? I just added the output expected. Thanks

Comment: Could you try to explain in words what is your loop trying to do? It's not quite clear to me.

Comment: @user32185 just added in words. thanks

Comment: If you want I can share a solution that works per batch of rules. But it could lead to weird results if the rules are not univocal.

Comment: @user32185 yes, please. Let me try your solution. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possible solution. Is not ideal as it using `apply`, which is faster than a loop but not as fast as a vectorial solution. I renamed `risk` as `risk_bin` in `rules`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'package': {0: 'basic', 1: 'medium', 2: 'premium', 3:'basic', 4:'medium', 5:'premium'},
   'risk_bin': {0: 'good/mid', 1: 'good/mid', 2: 'good/mid', 3:'bad', 4:'bad',5:'bad'},
   'A': {0:0.012,1:0.022,2:0.032,3:0.05,4:0.06,5:0.07},
   'B': {0:0.013,1:0.023,2:0.033,3:0.051,4:0.061,5:0.071},
   'C': {0:0.014,1:0.024,2:0.034,3:0.052,4:0.062,5:0.072},
   'D': {0:0.015,1:0.025,2:0.035,3:0.053,4:0.063,5:0.073}})
df = df[df.columns[[4,5,0,1,2,3]]]

rules = pd.DataFrame({'rule': {0: '1', 1: '2'},
   'product1': {0: 'B', 1: 'C'},
   'relantioship': {0:'=',1:'='},
   'product2': {0:'A',1:'D'},
   'symbol': {0:'+',1:'-'},
   'value': {0:0.05,1:0.10},
   'package':{0:'basic',1:'all'},
   'risk_bin': {0:'good/mid', 1:'bad'}})
rules = rules[rules.columns[[5,1,3,2,6,7,0,4]]]

def fun(row):
    if row["symbol"] == "+":
        row[row["product1"]] = row[row["product2"]] + row["value"]
    else:
        row[row["product1"]] = row[row["product2"]] - row["value"]
    return row

# here you look for all the rows where rules match with the given columns
df1 = pd.merge(df.reset_index(), rules, on=["package", "risk_bin"])
# here you what a rule for `all` package
df2 = pd.merge(df.reset_index(),
               rules[rules["package"]=='all'].loc[:, rules.columns != "package"],
               on=["risk_bin"])
# now you apply the function to both df
df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: fun(x), axis=1)
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: fun(x), axis=1)

#select the indices in df1 and df2
bad_idx = df.index.isin(df1["index"].tolist()+df2["index"].tolist())

#concat all together
res = pd.concat([df1[df.columns], df2[df.columns], df[~bad_idx]],ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @user32185